# Display the current step of a long process in a jQuery modal panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In my application, there is a page where the user can generate an Excel report. This generation may be relatively long (from 10 seconds to 5 minutes).
Currently, when the user clicks on the *Generate* button, there is a [jQuery modal panel](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) with a loading icon (a waiting popup).

Now, I want to provide a graphical indication of the current step of the Excel generation. For example, once the user has clicked on the button, the modal panel displayed will be:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|         ... Please wait ...         |
+-------------------------------------+
|  We are preparing your Excel file.  |
|                                     |
|  >> Finding unicorns in Database.   |
|  2. Reading "Database for dummies"  |
|  3. Downloading the Internet...     |
|  4. Write fake data in Excel file.  |
+-------------------------------------+
```

then, few seconds later, the modal panel will look like:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|         ... Please wait ...         |
+-------------------------------------+
|  We are preparing your Excel file.  |
|                                     |
|  1. Finding unicorns in Database.   |
|  >> Reading "Database for dummies"  |
|  3. Downloading the Internet...     |
|  4. Write fake data in Excel file.  |
+-------------------------------------+
```

and so on, until the Excel is available to the user.

My idea to implement that is to periodically poll the server with an Ajax request. The server will then return a JSon object with the list of steps (to make it a little bit generic) and the one that is active. Then, I will parse this object and display / refresh the list of steps.

I don't see technical issues here, as jQuery provides all the element to do that. But maybe there is already a jQuery plugin for such requirement. Do you know one?

In case I have to develop it, do you have any recommandation (mistake to avoid, etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a plugin for this because it is pretty simple. I have done a similar feature last week and the only thing you need to do is save the data you want to send to the client in a database while you generate your file and send continuous request from client to server to update the status. You can send a request every second, I simply waited to get a response from the server then if it wasn't finished I would just call the request sending function again and again.

EDIT: I would avoid storing the generation status messages in the session because if I'm not mistaken the session gets locked during http request and if you want to also send other requests while you wait for the generation you won't be able to access the session.